# Datatable doesn't bring all columns from SharePoint list

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, list-view, list-view-web-part, datatable

I programmatically created a library "DropDownLibrary" with some field "ReviewType"(text), "SubmittedDate"(datetime), "Created"(the sharepoint field)... and it works in the browser, I can insert new document and set field value.
But when I want to bind my listview with some fields , I put the list content in dataTable but SubmittedDate is empty in result:
with this message : **"SubmittedDate does not belong to table DropDownLibrary"**

```
     SPQuery objQuery = new SPQuery();    
    objQuery.ViewFields = string.Format(DROPDOWNLIBRARY_FIELDS, "AGENTID_FIELD","ID_FIELD", "CREATED_FIELD","SALES_FIELD", "SUBMITTEDDATE_FIELD"); ...
      DataTable fSDataTable = List.GetItems(objQuery).GetDataTable())
      var result = from fSDataTables in fSDataTable .AsEnumerable()
 select new {
 SubmittedDate = DataUtilities.GetSafeString(fSDataTables["SubmittedDate"])
  };
```

PS :When I try with "Created" it works,

```
var result = from fSDataTables in fSDataTable .AsEnumerable()
     select new {
     Created= DataUtilities.GetSafeString(fSDataTables["Created"])
      };
```

Any ideas ?
thanks

Comment: Did you get it working? have you tried below solution?

Comment: Is it working for you? Kindly post the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change these lines

```
SPQuery objQuery = new SPQuery();    
objQuery.ViewFields = string.Format(DROPDOWNLIBRARY_FIELDS, "AGENTID_FIELD","ID_FIELD", "CREATED_FIELD","SALES_FIELD", "SUBMITTEDDATE_FIELD"); ...
  DataTable fSDataTable = List.GetItems(objQuery).GetDataTable();
```

With below code

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
string[] viewFields = new string[5] { "DROPDOWNLIBRARY_FIELDS", "AGENTID_FIELD","ID_FIELD", "CREATED_FIELD","SALES_FIELD", "SUBMITTEDDATE_FIELD" };
query.Query = queryString;

  string queryViewFields = string.Empty;
  foreach (string viewField in viewFields)
  {
    string field = web.Fields[viewField];
    string queryViewField = string.Format("<FieldRef Name='{0}' />", field.InternalName);

    queryViewFields += queryViewField;
  }

  // To me, this queryViewFields also seems to be fine
query.ViewFields = queryViewFields;
DataTable fSDataTable = List.GetItems(objQuery).GetDataTable()
```

You will get all the results.

Comment: Did you tried it? Is it working for you? If not than please let me know so i can help you further.

Comment: in  : private const string DROPDOWNLIBRARY_FIELDS = "<FieldRef Name='{0}' /><FieldRef Name='{1}' /><FieldRef Name='{2}' /><FieldRef Name='{3}' /><FieldRef Name='{4}' /><FieldRef Name='{5}' /><FieldRef Name='{6}' /><FieldRef Name='{7}' /><FieldRef Name='{8}' /><FieldRef Name='{9}' /><FieldRef Name='{10}' />"; I was missing the last one {10}, so it brings 10 fields instead of 11 (SubmittedDate).

Comment: You need to check for all columns.